# MySQL: Table tbl_2_1_15 is full

Tags: mysql, size, limit, innodb

MySQL-Version: [running MySQL on Windows 7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtkeI.png)

Filesystem: NTFS

During an INSERT INTO tbl_2_1_15 SELECT ...-Query I get the message: tbl_2_1_15 is full. At this point the tbl_2_1_15 shows 24192665 entries with a select count(*)-Query. The table itself is an InnoDB table with the following configuration:

[info for tbl_2_1_15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sqtLC.png)

It consists of four columns:
ID1 int(11)
ID2 int(11)
ID3 int(11)
ID4 int(11)
value double

Why is the table full? Is there a size limit and how can I raise it?

System Info:
OS is Window 7 Professional Service Pack 1
MySQL-Server-Version is 5.7.15 for Win 32 on AMD 64 (how can I see if this is 32-bit or 64-bit?)

MySQL global variables:
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_data_file_path = 'ibdata1:12M:autoextend'

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: What's the MySQL error code? Your solution is probably here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43503/how-to-solve-the-table-is-full-with-innodb-file-per-table

Comment: @Eugene is probably on the right track. Looks like the total table size on disk is right up on a 4GB boundary. That tends to be a significant number in Windows environments.

Comment: What OS?  What version of MySQL?  32-bit?  How much disk space?  Etc.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_data_file_path';` and `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb_file_per_table';`

Comment: Hmmm... 32-bit mysql.  Still, that won't explain it -- MySQL has 'always' been able to create tables bigger than 4GB.  And I don't think Win 7 was that lame.

Comment: Hi!

OS is Window 7 Professional Service Pack 1;
innodb_file_per_table = 1;
MySQL-Server-Version is 5.7.15 for Win 32 on AMD 64 (how can I see if this is 32-bit or 64-bit?)

Answer (score 0):

We now switched to a linux server, so problems do not persist anymore.